# Why printf runs into error with n format specifier?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have some C code with a `%n` printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, j;
    i = printf( "something%n", &j );
    return i + j; 
}
```

There is no error in compilation and execution. `printf` prints the string "something".

Why my printf returns -1 and why it doesn't save the n parameter in j?

Here a photo while debugging..

[image: debug photo]

Comment: I think you meant to use scanf not printf. Please look into it.

Comment: No, printf with %n

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Microsoft C compiler and running your program on Windows, then by default, using %n with printf will indeed fail. This is because Microsoft views %n as a security risk and disables it by default in printf and related print formatting functions.

To enable %n add the following line early on in your program:

```
_set_printf_count_output(1);
```

This is documented in the important note on %n in the following help article:

Format specification syntax: printf and wprintf functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions

Comment: Yes thanks,you are right, i have already seen this anwer in some similar topics but my compiler( GNU GCC Compiler Codeblocks ) refuse that line. Maybe it will works with Visual c++ compiler...I don't know. In any case now i know what the ploblem is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code and verified, you can check it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BJIF5EUOI

Result:

[image]

Seems it works fine according to documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

`printf` returned total number of characters written, result stored at `i` variable

`%n` stored number of characters written so far under `j`

`main()` returned `i + j` - so 2x total number of characters written

Comment: thanks but here is my debugging https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJTcS.png

Comment: it's not essential for my project but i don't know why printf has this behavior...

Comment: At online debugger (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_debugger) it also works correctly: https://imgur.com/a/4ZYoVH1

Comment: For me these two things can happen at your side:
1) You have broken C debugger/compiler or general environment misconfiguration
2) Which leads to printf failure (that's why it returns -1 and "%n" not worked
Try check "error indicator" (ferror):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ (check "Return Value" documentation)

Comment: Even j value is wrong in image uploaded. I would suggest you to recompile it again use plain old gdb to debug. Something is wrong viewer in which you are monitoring

Comment: Yes i supposed something like that. My friend using CadeBlocks had the same issue also. Thanks you all!